# Visual-composer back end-editor not working with latest version of wordpress(Version 5.0)

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, visual-composer

let me know if anyone else, also having the same issue. it is working fine with older version but I just installed the latest version and now it's not working.

Comment: WPBakery Visual Composer has announced 27.11.2018 an update to version 5.6 to guarantee compatibility with Wordpress 5.0

Comment: Visual Composer will work with clasic editor, which is now available as Plugin. If Gutenberge installed, please uninstall it.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem today in morning when I have updated WordPress to latest version 5.

But I have fixed the Problem by updating the Visual-composer back end-editor to latest version.

Check this [link](https://codecanyon.net/item/visual-composer-page-builder-for-wordpress/242431). You can see Release Notes there that says `VER 5.6 - Update: Compatibility with WordPress 5.0.`

So just update your plugin & sure that will fix your problem.

Try it & let me know if you have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Use the plugin call classic editor.  It uses the old editor.  Do not use classic editor addon.  Just the standard classic editor plugin.

Comment: Great I just tried and its working fine now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Wordpress Version 4.9.9 
It is working for me.
[Download link](https://wordpress.org/wordpress-4.9.9.zip/)

Answer (score 0):

I can’t find Backend Editor, where is it?

The WordPress admin panel is a very unpredictable environment for such a complex product like Visual Composer. Because of that, we decided to remove Backend Editor in 2.0 version and focus our development on Frontend Editor. As a result, you as a user are getting a more stable and faster editor. Release cycles will become shorter and new features will be delivered to you faster.

To justify the “loss” we will introduce new “structured view” mode in Frontend Editor (similar how it was in the Backend Editor) and there is always Tree View mode available (a layer style representer and editor of your layout).

[official website](https://visualcomposer.com/help/faq/i-cant-find-backend-editor-where-is-it/)